# Fitting parameters from a multiparameter model are not calculated in a crescent order

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-analysis, sigmoid

I apologise for the somewhat confusing title.

I am trying to fit a specific set of data ([DATA FILE HERE](https://filebin.net/t15g91wujwi4hdez)) to a model comprised of three sigmoidal functions, as described below.

```
def sigmoid(p,x):
    x01,c1,k1,x02,c2,k2,x03,c3,k3,y0=p
    y = (c1 / (1 + np.exp(-k1*(x-x01)))) + (c2 / (1 + np.exp(-k2*(x-x02))))+(c3 / (1 + np.exp(-k3*(x-x03)))) + y0
    return y


#model for curve with 3 sigmoidal transitions, where:

# y0 = y initial value
# x0, x02, x03 = the x-value of the sigmoid's midpoint
# c1, c2, c3 = the curve's maximum value
# k1, k2, k3= the logistic growth rate or steepness of the curve
```

When I run the full script (which is provided further down), I get the following example as result:

[image: Result example]

As it is seen, the values for c, x0, and k are not in a crescent order (i.e.: c2 has a smaller value than c3, which per consequence has a smaller value than c1). Could anyone explain me why this is happening and how I can solve the issue? I do need the parameters to be in crescent order relative to x (c1>c2>c3), as I will later store them in variables to be used as statistical entities.

In some situations, I also get negative values for c, k, and x0, as elucidated in the following pictures

[image: Fitting parameters]

[image: Plot corresponding to the fitting parameters above]

Is there any way to solve this issue in order to always get positive values for the  fitting parameters? Or am I not doing the fitting properly?

Here is a sample of the code I'm running:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.optimize 
from scipy.optimize import  curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(p,x):
    x01,c1,k1,x02,c2,k2,x03,c3,k3,y0=p
    y = (c1 / (1 + np.exp(-k1*(x-x01)))) + (c2 / (1 + np.exp(-k2*(x-x02))))+(c3 / (1 + np.exp(-k3*(x-x03)))) + y0
    return y


#model for curve with 3 sigmoidal transitions, where:

# y0 = y intitial value,
# x0, x02, x03 = the x-value of the sigmoid's midpoint,
# c1, c2, c3 = the curve's maximum value
# k1, k2, k3= the logistic growth rate or steepness of the curve


def residuals(p,x,y):
    return y - sigmoid(p,x)


url=r'/Users/user/Downloads/RawDataEclipse (1).xlsx'

for i in range(12):

    #data raw
    df  = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name=i,sep='\s*,\s*') # we use index_col=0 to indicate that first row in the dataset is the index column 
    #df.rename(columns={ df.columns[1]: "Time_1", df.columns[3]: "Time_2"}) #rename columns which have the same name 
    x1=np.array(df['Time'], dtype=float)
    y1=np.array(df['Intensity330'], dtype=float)
    x2=np.array(df['Time.1'], dtype=float)
    y2=np.array(df['Intensity330'], dtype=float)
    x3=np.array(df['Time.2'], dtype=float)
    y3=np.array(df['Intensity490\'Time'], dtype=float)
    p_guess=(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

    #fits
    p1, cov1, infodict1, mesg1, ier1 = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residuals,p_guess,args=(x1,y1),full_output=1) 
    p2, cov2, infodict2, mesg2, ier2 = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residuals,p_guess,args=(x2,y2),full_output=1)
    p3, cov3, infodict3, mesg3, ier2 = scipy.optimize.leastsq(residuals,p_guess,args=(x3,y3),full_output=1)
    x011,c11,k11,x021,c21,k21,x031,c31,k31,y01=p1
    x012,c12,k12,x022,c22,k22,x032,c32,k32,y02=p2
    x013,c13,k13,x023,c23,k23,x033,c33,k33,y03=p3
    print('''\

        DATA FIT 330 a.u.:


        x0 step 1= {x011}
        x0 step 2= {x021}
        x0 step 3= {x031}
        y0= {y01}
        c step 1= {c11}
        c step 2= {c21}
        c step 3= {c31}
        k step 1 = {k11}
        k step 2 = {k21}
        k step 3 = {k31}
        '''.format(x011=x011,c11=c11,k11=k11,x021=x021,c21=c21,k21=k21,x031=x031,c31=c31,k31=k31,y01=y01))

    print('''\

        DATA FIT 350 a.u.:


        x0 step 1= {x012}
        x0 step 2= {x022}
        x0 step 3= {x032}
        y0= {y02}
        c step 1= {c12}
        c step 2= {c22}
        c step 3= {c32}
        k step 1 = {k12}
        k step 2 = {k22}
        k step 3 = {k32}
        '''.format(x012=x012,c12=c12,k12=k12,x022=x022,c22=c22,k22=k22,x032=x032,c32=c32,k32=k32,y02=y02))

    print('''\

        DATA FIT 490 a.u.:


        x0 step 1= {x013}
        x0 step 2= {x023}
        x0 step 3= {x033}
        y0= {y03}
        c step 1= {c13}
        c step 2= {c23}
        c step 3= {c33}
        k step 1 = {k13}
        k step 2 = {k23}
        k step 3 = {k33}
        '''.format(x013=x013,c13=c13,k13=k13,x023=x023,c23=c23,k23=k23,x033=x033,c33=c33,k33=k33,y03=y03))


    pxp1=sigmoid(p1,x1)
    pxp2=sigmoid(p2,x2)
    pxp3=sigmoid(p3,x3)

    #Plot the results
    plt.plot(x1, y1, '.', label='data i330') 
    plt.plot(x1, pxp1, label='fit i330')
    plt.plot(x2, y2, 'v', label='data i350')
    plt.plot(x2, pxp2, label='fit i350')
    plt.plot(x3, y3, '^', label='data i490')
    plt.plot(x3, pxp3, label='fit i490')
    plt.xlabel('Time (min)')
    plt.ylabel('Intrinsic Fluorescence (a.u.)') 
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data file?

Comment: Here is the link to the file https://filebin.net/t15g91wujwi4hdez. A link to the data can also now be found in the first lines of the post @JamesPhillips

Comment: Is there a strong argument for using the sum of 3 sigmoidal functions for the fit? It seems that there is only one transition on the presented data, and also the negative values obtained indicates that all the parameters are not relevant... I would like to test a simpler function (maybe based on [Generalised_logistic_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function))

Comment: I have tried and have scripts for only one and two transitions. The problem is that, when the script only accounts for one transition, the fit is not good at all. If you pay closer attention, you will find out that, actually, the majority of the data, when plotted, reveals two transitions. This is specially evident in the first part of the curves, as a straight line (with stepness=0) that is characteristic of sigmoidal functions before and after the log growth is not observed. This was the major argument to fit 3 sigmoidal functions as this model gave the best fits @xdze2

Comment: What are you trying to extract from the data? The position of the big step? Then I would fit with just one sigmoidal function near the step. Or do you just need a nice fit? Then a spline fit would do. I

Comment: @ChristianK. do you know what code do I exactly need to make it fit close to the step? I would still like to take both the smaller and the large transition, when there are two of them. And as I have previously mentioned, when only one transition is accounted in the model, the fitting, and therefore its parameters and middle point, will not be properly calculated

Comment: @Rodrigosp96 Actually neither of the steps has the form of a sigmoidal function so it will be hard to get a good fit. Don't you have a better model? To get the the location of the biggest step I would look at the derivative.